# How to handle recent variable change resulting in level-switch in time series modeling?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, change-point

I developed a script to run time series models on people data, and I re-run the Arima model fitting/forecast reconciliation algorithm monthly as new data comes in. I use the grouped/hierarchical time series method laid out in 11.4 of Hyndman's Forecasting: Principles and Practice (https://otexts.com/fpp3/tourism.html). I run a model for each variable combination, and one of the variables is race.

Over time there have been changes to personnel race category assignment. These shifts have not historically required intervention on my part since they were years ago and the Arima model adjusted.

However, this past month, there was a major race code switch that resulted in many employees from one race group ('X') getting re-assigned to a different race group ('Y'). Unadjusted, the time series models for X group forecast a continued major decline (going below zero since I do not utilize lambda transformations), and group Y forecasted an insane increase. Fundamentally, I think the race code change is a level-switch, and I expect trends (variance, drift, etc) to be the same for groups X and Y but with a new mean.

It is important to note that it is not possible to re-assign historical data with the new race groupings.

Is there a way to program into the models a sudden level-switch? My more rudimentary idea was to fit a Naive model for groups where the most recent data point is some % different than the last three or four month mean.

Any help or ideas would be much appreciated!